# Finite state Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Under what conditions a Markov chain can be considered as finite (and not infinite)?

Thank you!

Comment: A finite state (discrete-time) Markov chain is a sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ all of which take values from a finite set $\mathcal{X}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characterization of a Markov Chain as *finite or infinite* refers to the state space $Ω$ in which the Markov Chain takes it's values. Thus, a finite (infinite) Markov chain is a process which moves among the elements of a finite (infinite) set $Ω$. In other words, if $X_n$ describes the state of the process at time $n$ then $$X_n\inΩ$$ If $Ω$ is finite f.e. $$Ω=\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1, n\}$$ then $(X_n)_n$ is called a finite Markov Chain, otherwise if $Ω$ is infinite. f.e. 
$$Ω=\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1, n, \ldots\}$$ then the Markov Chain $(X_n)_n$ is calles infinite.

Comment: Calling $\Omega$ the state space of a Markov chain is probably the *worst* choice one could make.

Comment: Another option would be to try to *understand* it. Let me help you: in probability, what is $\Omega$ used for, 99% of the time?

Comment: Last try: quasi universally, $\Omega$ is the *source set* of the random variables $X_n$, not their target set. Of course, as I said from the start, this is only a matter of notation. Still.

Comment: ((Comments (including specific threat) now deleted by the OP.))

Comment: My last comment means what it says, as each of my comments (which I never delete afterwards).

Comment: ((New comment deleted by the OP.))